# Have two (permalinks) urls for a same custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

I have an specific situation which I´ll try to explain. In the website I developing right now we have fairs (event) and every fair has a profile page. Lets call ns_fair custom post type and its loaded with permalink `http://localhost/website/fairs/fair/{name)`.

Hi have a page with the permalink `http://localhost/website/past-fairs/` where I list the archive fairs with a custom WP_Query Loop. When I click a fair, loads in `http://localhost/website/fairs/fair/{name)`. and I need to load in `http://localhost/website/past-fairs/fairs/fair/{name)`.

It´s the same custom post, just loaded with another permalink, for website structure purposes only.

That´s possible? Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm....

I'm not sure this is possible since the fairs are not located under the "past fairs" CPT. However, the URL structure shouldn't be too critical as long as the navigation on your site is setup in a way that makes sense.

Is there any other reason you want this behavior other than personal preference?

Comment: I just think it's the right thing to do, to keep coherence in the structure of the website, but I could be wrong, of course. You think I should forget about this? Can I get a link or reference to talk about it? Thanks in advance for your help.